# How to store numbers greater than 4095 in Risc-V "10000": operand is out of range

Tags: riscv, rars-simulator

Hi I'm trying to store a number for division purposes but I'm getting this error when I try to assemble the program

"10000": operand is out of range

the code having a problem looks like this

```
addi t1, zero, 10000
```

this line of code did work with smaller numbers, with 1-2047 working 2048-4095 giving

Unsigned value is too large to fit into a sign-extended immediate

and numbers greater giving the same error message

Comment: this is what the pseudo instruction li is for.  same issues with any fixed length instruction set (arm, mips, etc).    in this case they specify a pseudo instruction  li ti,10000

Comment: and then the assembler chooses, ideally, the optimal instructions to complete that, for rv32 it should be no more than two instructions, for rv64 of course can be more, but at the same time it may do a pc relative load from a nearby pool which is another option.

Comment: If you can't do something in one instruction, then use two or as many as needed.  Also, see how a compiler does it [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/dnPf1d7TY)

Answer (score 0):

Immediate values, such as the one you're trying to write to the register file, have a fixed bit-length which is defined by the instruction format.
Please see section 2.2 in the [official RISC-V spec](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2016/EECS-2016-118.pdf) for a nice diagram.

In RV32I, I-type instructions like `addi` have a 12-bit immediate, meaning that they can represent 4096 (2^12). You can always shift bits left and add another value to it to create larger values.